# A problem with relationships between tables, and data overload caused by it

Tags: relationship, sql-server-2014

[image]

I don't know how to explain my exact problem, but in any case I will try:

In the item_period table, if I wanted to modify any data and this data was used in the invoices, for example, it will create a new period for the item data, and when creating this period I will have to copy all units and all pricing in the new period, in my view this will cause a large inflation of the base Data, especially since the items may be 100000 or more, in this case the volume of data will be very large, my method may be incorrect, but I use it in order to make each period take its correct data..

And for work, I forgot to set the **billing table**, because it depends on entering the item on the **id_item_rate** and not the name of the item or unit, so that it will take the **id_item_rate** to know the price and to know the item and its unit

**My question here is how to avoid data inflation if you modify any data in the item_period table**

Comment: What is your question here? Considering you have tagged C# I *assume* you want the solution in C#, so what is your existing application code to attempt to resolve your unasked question?

Comment: My question here is how to avoid data inflation if you modify any data in the item_period table

Comment: `when creating this period I will have to copy all units and all pricing in the new period` why will you *have to* do so? And why are you using a deprecated version of SQL Server

Comment: Copy the data for the new period in order to find out the prices of this new period